# jQuery load() can't load php page with text file?

Tags: php, jquery

jQuery code:

```
function sorting(){
  $(".search_result_employee").load("include/searchedResult.php", {sort: "SORT_DESC"});
}
```

php code:

```
$array = file("data/employees.txt");



$row = intdiv(count($array), 4);
if (count($array)%4 != 0){
    $row++;
}

//$row = round(count($array)/4);
$x = $z = 0;
for ($x; $x < $row; $x++){
    echo '<div class="row my-4">';
    for ($y=0; $y <= 3; $y++){
        if (isset($array[$z])) {
            $name = explode("| ", $array[$z]);
            $eName = $name[0];
            $eDepartment = $name[7];
            $eProfile = end($name);

            echo '
            <div class="col-md">
                <a href="displayInfo.php?name='."$eName".'" class="grey_bg p-2 m-1 employeeCard">
                    <img src="employeesProfile/'."$eProfile".'" alt="profile" class="profile"/>
                    '."$eName".'<br/>
                        <span>'."$eDepartment".'</span>
                </a>
            
            </div>
            ';
        }
        $z++;
        
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

First go in the page using

```
<?php include("include/searchedResult.php"); ?>
```

The page can found the file. Howver, after clicked the button, the jQuery load() the `include/searchResu;t.php` page. Then, the file doesn't exist. First time is working properly thensecond time can't. Anyone know how to solve this?

this is the error:

> Warning: file(data/employees.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\COS30020\include\searchedResult.php on line 14

Comment: the include directory is likely not availabele to the browser - look in the network tab

Comment: Please share more details. Are you facing any error message? Also, the given code does not echo the loaded file, so adding it to the markup will obviously not work

Comment: the text file. Second time can't find the text file

Comment: My guess is that you have the php in two places and when you load from /include, the data is not in the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including files in PHP, all relative paths will be relative from the first entry PHP-file.

If `index.php` includes `searchResult.php`, then `file('data/employees.txt')` will be relative from the `index.php`-file, not the `searchResult.php`-file.

If you call the `searchResult.php`-file directly, then it will be relative from `searchResult.php` (which then is the entry file).

Solve this by using the magic constant `__DIR__`, which contains the absolute path to the file it's written in.

So it should be:

```
file(__DIR__ . '/relative/path/from/this/file/data/employees.txt')
```

Comment: this is what I want! Really thank you sir. Never think about this before

Comment: @VoonTaoTan - If the answer solved your issue, please accept it.