# get root folder in each php file

Tags: php

I have a include issue which I can't solve alone.

This is my folder structure:

[image]

for better explanation:
There is a main folder "inc" (outside from accounting) and a subfolder inc (inset from accounting)

in the subfolder "inc" is a functions.php
which has the following line:

```
require_once('../inc/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

this works fine !

in the "ajax" folder I have the file task.php wit this line:

```
require '../inc/functions.php';
```

Here I get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(../inc/tcpdf/tcpdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /volume1/web/accounting/inc/functions.php
```

Where is my mistake

Comment: it's better to use absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery load() can't load php page with text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433225/jquery-load-cant-load-php-page-with-text-file) - The answer to that question should explain the issue you're having as well.

Comment: take a look to @MagnusEriksson link. he explained well in his answear. "...When including files in PHP, all relative paths will be relative from the first entry PHP-file. ..."

Comment: is there a variable available for the relative path?

Comment: @hassan I disagree. Makes your code much less portable

Comment: What do you mean? What variable? Available for what? There's no specific variable to get the root project folder, if that is what you mean. PHP can't know which folder you consider project root. Did you read the answer for the suggested duplicate?

Comment: @ADyson make sense , you are totally right.

Comment: Why not use a proper classloader for this? At least, TCPDF could get installed using Composer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use relative paths for include. Relative paths have the "current working directory" as a reference. The working directory is not fixed and can also be changed by code. Always use the constant

```
__DIR__
```

for your paths. This gives you an absolute path relative to the file where you write it:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../inc/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've made a couple of changes: Firstly, I've changed the wording to mention "current working directory", which is the term people will need to search for if they want to understand more how relative paths work. Secondly, I've removed the parentheses around the argument to `require_once` - they're not actually part of the syntax, and while using them works, it can lead to confusion, e.g. `require_once ($foo) . $bar` is the same as `require_once ($foo . $bar)`, not `(require_once $foo) . $bar`